# Trying to add classes to multiple divs by hovering over one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Basically, I have a page made up of five vertical stripes of different colors. These will eventually be links to different sections or something like that.

Check out this fiddle to get a general idea of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/nolbear/4fea3/

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$('#banner1').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('forty');
  $('#banner2').toggleClass('twenty');
  $('#banner3').toggleClass('twenty');
  $('#banner4').toggleClass('ten');
  $('#banner5').toggleClass('ten');     
});
```

I'm trying to get it so that when you hover over the top stripe, it becomes larger, and all the other stripes get smaller to compensate. The stripes should take up the entire height of the page at all times (that's why I'm using percentages).

I don't understand why the code I've written isn't working, I've taken it directly from other StackOverflow questions that have been answered and it still won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you didn't set jQuery in your fiddle

Secondary, you set the height by id which overrides the class values so instead I styled them by class.

http://jsfiddle.net/4fea3/4/

```
<div id="banner1" class="banner">
</div>

<div id="banner2" class="banner">
</div>

<div id="banner3" class="banner">
</div>

<div id="banner4" class="banner">
</div>

<div id="banner5" class="banner">
</div>

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0.0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease 0.0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason this would work on jsfiddle, but not when I try to put it on Dreamweaver?

Comment: @NolanManning I only can guess you are not putting it correctly. You ARE including jquery js file, right? Your fiddle didn't have it.

Comment: Yes, I put it in the head: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> Is that an old version?

Comment: @NolanManning Change it to: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` And see if it works

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference :/

Comment: Here is my code running on my server: www.nolanmanning.com/bannerz

Maybe someone can discern what I was doing wrong from this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, it's just the css that is not working.  You've applied `height: 20%` to each banner, and then `height: x%` to each css class that you wish to change the height of the banners.  Unfortunately the first `height: 20%` will override this.  I've used `!important` to fix it in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4fea3/3/

Ideally you would avoid the `!important` and update your styling to override correctly when the classes are added.